# valum uploader return success

Tags: handler

I am using valum uploader with asp.net generic handler and It's working totally fine , however I am having a problem return "success" , here is my code which is always understood as fail by fileuploader.js .

here is my response code :

```
      context.Response.AddHeader("result", "success");
            context.Response.AddHeader("success", "true");
            context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
```

Answer (score 2):

This was kind of tripping me up as well. My issue was that I wasn't using the [fileuploader.css](https://raw.github.com/valums/file-uploader/master/client/fileuploader.css) that comes with the uploader. If you don't use that, then the failure message will be visible even on successful downloads. It is always present, but it is just hidden when a file uploads successfully, and is shown when there is a failure. Here's the relevant css:

```
.qq-upload-failed-text {
     display: none; 
}
```